# iframe audio with live streaming embed not working properly (Zoom)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, iframe, live-streaming

I have written an iframe code to embed a Zoom live stream of our church service on our website. http://www.firstchurchofgodjctn.org. It works "almost" perfectly, except it will not trigger the audio. Video streams perfectly, but there is no sound. I have tried almost everything I know to do - to override Chrome and MS Edge's autoplay issues - and I am at a loss. Upon loading the live stream (when the meeting starts) I get a prompt to "upgrade" my browser, computer audio is disabled. I can preview the html page I built through my design software, and the audio works. (I'm a self-taught programmer, so I'm surprised I've gotten this far!)
Here is the code:

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: <div class="iframe-container" style="overflow: hidden; padding-top: 56.25%; position: relative;">
     <iframe  allow="microphone; camera; fullscreen; autoplay"
            sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-presentation" style="border: 0; height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%;" src="https://zoom.us/wc/0000000000/join?prefer=0&pwd=0000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>